# Localization of biblatex headings

Tags: biblatex, babel

My Bibliography is subdivided into 2 parts (published / online references). I would like to get an automatic localization of the 2 subheadings, which is controled by the setting of the babel package.

Example with `\usepackage[english]{babel}`:

> **Bibliography**
>   *List of Published References*
>   Author, A. (2013) - This is the Title.
>   Author, B. (2013) - This is the second Title.
>   
>   *List of Online References*
>   Author, A. (2013) - URL http://www.test.com

Example with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`:

> **Quellenverzeichnis**
>   *Literaturverzeichnis*
>   Author, A. (2013) - This is the Title.
>   Author, B. (2013) - This is the second Title.
>   
>   *Liste der Internetquellen*
>   Author, A. (2013) - URL http://www.test.com

My commands to setup the bibliography look like this:

```
\printbibheading[title={\bibname}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={\pubname},nottype=online]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={\unpubname},type=online]
```

The commands `\pubname` and `\unpubname` are not defined right now. I don't know how to.

I thought it would be best to work with new bibliography strings, since the localization of `\bibname` works this way. Therefore I introduced the 2 bibliography strings `publishedSources` and `unpublishedSources` and defined them afterwards for the different languages. Unfortunately I have no clue about getting those values into the `title` key of `\printbibliography`:

```
\NewBibliographyString{publishedSources,unpublishedSources}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    publishedSources   = {List of Published References},
    unpublishedSources = {List of Online References},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    bibliography       = {Quellenverzeichnis},
    publishedSources   = {Literaturverzeichnis},
    unpublishedSources = {Liste der Internetquellen},
}
```

Comment: Does `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title=\bibstring{publishedSources},nottype=online]` work for you?

Comment: @moewe This looked so promissing. Unfortunately I get an `Undefined control sequence` error for `\bibstring`. It seems like you could only use this command wihtin certain environments. Even if I put `\bibstring{bibliography}` in the middle of my document, I will get the error and latex prints the term in curly braces (bibliography), but won't get the value of the bibliography string.

Comment: Yes, I really thought that was the solution, but - as you say - the `\bibstring` macro seems to work only within certain `BibLaTex` environments and macros.

Comment: @FrogThomas Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller Sorry for my delay. I was short on time.
Yes, your answer solved my problem. Nevertheless I am shocked of the fact, that a hack seems to be the only possible way. Maybe this is an interesting request for future biblatex features. I actually need this for a documentclass which I am building. It is supposed to support multiple languages. I do not think this is all that uncommon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a way, but it needs to hack some `biblatex` internal code.

Keep your definitions:

```
\NewBibliographyString{publishedSources,unpublishedSources}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    publishedSources   = {List of Published References},
    unpublishedSources = {List of Online References},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    bibliography       = {Quellenverzeichnis},
    publishedSources   = {Literaturverzeichnis},
    unpublishedSources = {Liste der Internetquellen},
}
```

and then add in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@defbibstrings#1#2{%
  \def\do##1{\csundef{abx@lstr@##1}\csundef{abx@sstr@##1}}%
  \abx@dostrings
  \csuse{abx@strings@#1}%
  \setkeys{blx@lbx}{#2}%
  \let\do\blx@defbibstrings@i
  \csxdef{abx@strings@#1}{\abx@dostrings}%
  \csgappto{abx@strings@#1}{%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @bibliography}
      {\letcs\bibname{\abx@str @bibliography}}
      {\let\bibname\@empty}%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @references}
      {\letcs\refname{\abx@str @references}}
      {\let\refname\@empty}%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @shorthands}
      {\letcs\losname{\abx@str @shorthands}}
      {\let\losname\@empty}
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @publishedSources}
      {\letcs\pubname{\abx@str @publishedSources}}
      {\let\pubname\@empty}
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @unpublishedSources}
      {\letcs\unpubname{\abx@str @unpublishedSources}}
      {\let\unpubname\@empty}
    }
  }
\makeatother
```

Thus the MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{publishedSources,unpublishedSources}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    publishedSources   = {List of Published References},
    unpublishedSources = {List of Online References},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    bibliography       = {Quellenverzeichnis},
    publishedSources   = {Literaturverzeichnis},
    unpublishedSources = {Liste der Internetquellen},
}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@defbibstrings#1#2{%
  \def\do##1{\csundef{abx@lstr@##1}\csundef{abx@sstr@##1}}%
  \abx@dostrings
  \csuse{abx@strings@#1}%
  \setkeys{blx@lbx}{#2}%
  \let\do\blx@defbibstrings@i
  \csxdef{abx@strings@#1}{\abx@dostrings}%
  \csgappto{abx@strings@#1}{%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @bibliography}
      {\letcs\bibname{\abx@str @bibliography}}
      {\let\bibname\@empty}%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @references}
      {\letcs\refname{\abx@str @references}}
      {\let\refname\@empty}%
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @shorthands}
      {\letcs\losname{\abx@str @shorthands}}
      {\let\losname\@empty}
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @publishedSources}
      {\letcs\pubname{\abx@str @publishedSources}}
      {\let\pubname\@empty}
    \ifcsdef{\abx@str @unpublishedSources}
      {\letcs\unpubname{\abx@str @unpublishedSources}}
      {\let\unpubname\@empty}
    }
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{itzhaki}\cite{wassenberg}\cite{aksin}\cite{angenendt}

\printbibheading[title={\bibname}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={\pubname},nottype=online]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={\unpubname},type=online]

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]